# Updating ember-moment element when reloading a route in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, momentjs

I have an Ember app that uses [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment).

The application defines a model for `site` objects:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  lastPoll: DS.attr('date'),
  status: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The `index` route loads site #1 when activated:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('site', 1);
  }
});
```

The template for this route is fairly simple:

```
{{moment-from-now model.lastPoll}}: {{model.status}}
```

All of this works as intended. However, I would like to reload the route every thirty seconds.

Thus, I have expanded the route as follows:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('site', 1);
  },

  afterModel() {
    this.set('_timer',
      Ember.run.later(this, () => {
        this.refresh();
      }, 30 * 1000)
    );
  },

  deactivate() {
    Ember.run.cancel(this.get('_timer'));
  }
});
```

The status updates when the data returned by the API changes. However, the relative time displayed in the template does not change. I am assuming Ember sees that `lastPoll` has not changed and does not update the element containing the relative time, even though the current time has changed (and therefore the relative time as well).

What is the correct approach for ensuring that the relative time is updated when the route is reloaded?

Comment: Yes I think you're right - you might want to use a date string, `attr('string')`. Working with references caused multiple problems for me (like forgetting that I need to reassign or clone a date/moment object for Ember to get changes...)

Comment: It should work. Can you provide a not working twiddle? However *don't* use `this.refresh();` for the reload! Just call `model.reload()`!

Comment: I may understood you wrong but are you looking for [`interval` argument of moment helper](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment/blob/v7.8.0/README.md#common-optional-named-arguments)?